# Error in IE11 caused by babel polyfill - delegate.iterator.return

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

Hope to get some help with following:

### **The problem**

@babel/polyfill causes error in IE11:

```
SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier
```

Debugger point on the line:

```
if (delegate.iterator.return) {
```

in the function `maybeInvokeDelegate()` in `regenerator-runtime` plugin.

**But**

Problem occures **only in test environment**. When I run my aplication locally, with exactly same build, same browser it works just fine. It contains same code, but it doesn't break anything.

### **What I've already tried:**

1. [babel-plugin-transform-member-expression-literals](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-member-expression-literals.html) doesn't seem to help.
2. I tried to replace @babel/polyfill with only necessary polyfills but I failed. To much errors breaking application which are hard to catch/debug/understand.
3. Set `useBuiltIns: "usage"` in `.babelrc` but faced a problem with way it imports necessary modules. I'm going to give this one more try.
4. I looked through all same issues with regeerator-runtime and babel-polyfill on github, but haven't found working solution.

### **Config**

At the moment I'm requiring @babel/polyfill in webpack config and use it as an entry point. I believe I don't even need regenerator-runtime, because as far as I understand it used for async function (maybe I'm mistaken) and we don't use them.

I'm not using babel loader for webpack but run babel for `/dist` directory after webpack.

**My babelrc:**

```
{
    plugins: ["transform-member-expression-literals"],
    presets: [
        [ "@babel/preset-env",
          {
              useBuiltIns: "entry",
              modules: "false",
              targets: {
                  ie: 11
              }
          }]
    ]
}
```

**webpack.config**

```
require("@babel/polyfill")

const getDefaultConfig = env => ({
  mode: "development",
  entry: ["whatwg-fetch", "@babel/polyfill", "./src/index.js"],
... })
```

I have updated all babel packages to latest versions.

Appreciate any help or ideas.

Comment: have you seen this? https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4255

Comment: @Romko, thanks. I wonder how I missed this point. Problem is not in the described error. Without dev tools opened, app is not running and when I open dev tools it switches to IE7 emulation eventually. Maybe it happens after page reload or I don't know when.

Comment: @Romko, you can post this as answer . I should accept it because you saved my day. :) I had another problem - compatibility mode for intranet sites, but couldn't find it because dev tools pointed me in wrong direction.

Comment: sure, glad it helped :)

Comment: <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge"> added ?

Comment: @zloctb no, didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the link below

[github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4255](http://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4255)

Comment: link only answers are not particularly useful