# IE break with problem delegate.iterator.return

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Webpack create bundle and in console I saw error:

> Expected identifier

```
if (delegate.iterator.return) {...}
```

Why my bundle is different for Chrome and IE11 ?And this part of code is absent for Chrome bundle? 
I have file .browserlistrc

```
# Browsers that we support

IE 11
> 1%
```

I found this similar question but it didn't helped for me.

[Error in IE11 caused by babel polyfill - delegate.iterator.return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593298/error-in-ie11-caused-by-babel-polyfill-delegate-iterator-return)

Comment: why did the similar question (and more importantly answer) not help you?

Comment: Try `delegate.iterator["return"]`

Comment: delegate.iterator.return it's not my code) It's code from node_modules

Comment: "*I found this similar question but it didn't helped for me*" - why does it not apply? IE compatibility mode sounds like the most likely culprit.